# How to calculate dependent probability?

Tags: probability

```
                                    INTRO
```

Total number of red and white balls = 100

Number of red balls = 92

Number of white balls = 8

**Question A**
- Express a probability for white balls

```
  A) My answer:
```

Pr (of white balls) = 0.08

*My calculations:*
Pr (red balls) = 0.92 = 92 %  , 23/25 = 92/100

Pr (white balls) = 0.08 = 8 % ,   2/25 = 8/100

---

**Question B**
- Express a distribution of an random variable X
X = number of balls (Red & White) n=1,2,3,4,5 
Use the probability you from question 1

```
 B) My thinking :
```

Red balls = x1
White balls = x2

X = (x1+ x2)

---

**Question C**

Calculate the probability from the following events:

C1 - Will find precisely 2 red balls within the 5 selected? Yes/No, explain your reasoning!

C2 - You will find at least 2 red balls within the 5 selected? Yes/No, explain your reasoning!

```
    My thinking B:
```

---

So say I use this equation:

Pr(X=x) :nCr (n,x) p^x (1-p)^(n-x)

But if I am to take 1 ball from the first try, there will be 99 balls let in the second try and 98 balls in the third try and so on… in the 10:th try there will be 90 balls left which means that the entire probability of balls would change after each try, no matter the colour...
Is there a formula that take THIS in account? if not, do you know which formula works in this case?

Help on this one would mean *ALOT*...

Answer (score 0):

**Part A)** Your answer is correct.

**Part B)** I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, so please keep that in mind with my response.

n = 1 ball drawn:

P(r) = 92%

P(w) = 8%

n = 2 balls drawn:

P(r,r) = ${\frac{92}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{91}{99}}$

P(w,w) = ${\frac{8}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{7}{99}}$

P (r,w) = ${\frac{92}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{8}{99}}$

Note that red then white is no different than white followed by red.  This is explained better in the explanation for Part C1.

n = 3 balls drawn:

P(r,r,r) = ${\frac{92}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{91}{99}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{90}{98}}$

P(w,w,w) = ${\frac{8}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{7}{99}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{6}{98}}$

P(r,w,w) = ${\frac{92}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{8}{99}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{7}{98}}$

P(r,r,w) = ${\frac{92}{100}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{91}{99}}$ $\cdot$ ${\frac{8}{98}}$

Hopefully you can see how this continues.

**Part C1)** No

Probability the first ball is red: ${\frac{92}{100}}$

Probability the second ball is red: ${\frac{91}{99}}$

Probability the third ball is white: ${\frac{8}{98}}$

Probability the fourth ball is white: ${\frac{7}{97}}$

Probability the fifth ball is white: ${\frac{6}{96}}$

To find the total probability of all these events happening, multiply each individual probability.

$\frac{(92\cdot91\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6)}{(100\cdot99\cdot98\cdot97\cdot96)}$ = ${\frac{2812992}{9034502400}}$ = $\frac{43953}{141164100}$ = 0.031136%

As you can see, this is extremely low. Please note that the order of the balls drawn does not matter.  The numerator is always going to be $(r)$$(r-1)$$(w)$$(w-1)$$(w-2)$ where r represents the number of red balls and w represents the number of white balls.

The denominator will always be $(t)$$(t-1)$$(t-2)$$(t-3)$$(t-4)$ where t is the total number of balls.

**Part C2)** Yes

This problem is better to approach by finding the probability that the *opposite* will happen and subtracting that probability from 1.

What is the probability of exactly one red ball? Use the same method as part C1.

$\frac{8}{100}$$\cdot$$\frac{7}{99}$$\cdot$$\frac{6}{98}$$\cdot$$\frac{5}{97}$$\cdot$$\frac{92}{96}$ = 0.001710774907%

What is the probability of exactly zero red balls? Use the same method as part C1.

$\frac{8}{100}$$\cdot$$\frac{7}{99}$$\cdot$$\frac{6}{98}$$\cdot$$\frac{5}{97}$$\cdot$$\frac{4}{96}$ = 0.00007438151768%

Add these probabilities and subtract the total from 1.

$1-(1.785*10^{-5})$ or (100% - 0.001785%) = 99.9982%